# How to evaluate a tricky limit to check convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to evaluate the below limit to see if the corresponding sequence $f_n(t)$ converges:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t)$

= $\lim_{n \to \infty } e^{(t-1) (q^0 + q^1 + q^2 + \ldots + q^{n-1})}$

= $e^{(t-1) (1/(1-q))}$

= $e^{(t-1)/(1-q)}$

Is this limit evaluation correct / using the right approach?

I am essentially just using the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series here $= 1/(1-q)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$f_n(t) = e^{(t-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^k}$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n}(t) = e^{(t-1)\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^k}$$
since the exponential function is continuous. Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^k = \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$, if $|q|<1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^k = \frac{1}{1-q}$ giving
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n}(t) = e^{\frac{t-1}{1-q}}$$
as you have obtained!

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the steps in the limit evaluation!